# Laravel - Validate required based on condition in Request Rules

Tags: laravel

I have this request rule in my Laravel-5.8 code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'activate_msf' => [
            'nullable',
                Rule::unique('appraisal_parameters')->where(function ($query) {
                return $query->where('company_id', $this->company_id)
                        ->where('activate_msf', $this->activate_msf);
                })
        ],        
        'max_internal_respondent' => [
            'nullable',
            'numeric',
            'min:1',
            'max:30',
            'gt:min_internal_respondent',
        ],             
        'min_internal_respondent' => [
            'nullable',
            'numeric',
            'min:1',
            'max:30',
        ],   
    ];
}
```

activate_msf is tinyint(1) which could either be 0 or 1.

How do I validate min_internal_respondent and max_internal_respondent to be required only when activate_msf = 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [required_if](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if) rule to achieve that validation:

```
 public
    function rules()
    {
        $rules= [
            'activate_msf' => [
                'nullable',
                Rule::unique('appraisal_parameters')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('company_id', $this->company_id)
                        ->where('activate_msf', $this->activate_msf);
                })
            ],
            'max_internal_respondent' => [
                'required_if:activate_msf,1',
                'numeric',
                'min:1',
                'max:30',
                'gt:min_internal_respondent',
            ],
            'min_internal_respondent' => [
                'required_if:activate_msf,1',
                'numeric',
                'min:1',
                'max:30',
            ],
        ];
    }
```